# Bit shift operator replacement in c

Tags: c, bit-shift

How can I replace the `>>` operator? For example in this case (bit representation):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() { 

    unsigned int x; 
    char str[65];
    char *res; 

    scanf("%i", &x); 
    res = str + 64;
    *res = 0;

    do { 

        res--;
        if ( x & 1 ) 
            *res = '1';
        else
            *res = '0';
        x >>= 1;

    } while(x != 0);

    printf("%s\n", res); 
}
```

Comment: A right shift by one bit is similar to a divide by two.

Comment: You mean, `x /= 2` instead of `x >>= 1`?

Comment: Please format your code correctly, just like the samples in your C text book.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? The usage of `>>` reflects your intention.

Comment: ... and you also forgot to initialize `res`. You probably want `char *res = str`.

Comment: "How can I replace the >> operator?" --> With `unsigned int x; `, `x >>= 1;` and `x /= 2;` are functionally the same.

Comment: `unsigned int x;  scanf("%i", &x);` is a problem.  Use `scanf("%u", &x);` to scan in `unsigned`.

Comment: If you intend to change `x` to `int` (maybe a 64-bit `int`), use `char str[66];` for the potential `INT_MIN` representable as `"-1000...63 total zeros...000"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are only valid for **unsigned** number `x` (Thanks @Groo for correction).

`x>>1` means right shifting `x` in its binary representation by one digit, which is equivalent to dividing it by 2 and only keep the quotient, discarding the remainder.

The line in your program can be replaced with

```
x /= 2;
```

In case someone need it,

```
x <<= 1;
```

is equivalent to (without considering overflow)

```
x *= 2;
```

Comment: It's worth noting shifting is equivalent to dividing by 2 only for unsigned numbers. The result is implementation defined, but `-1 >> 1` and `-1 / 2` will most likely return different results.

Comment: Good point. I will amend my answer.

Comment: thank you so much, but can i possibly make it work with signed numbers?

Comment: @user9088013 If you want "possibly make it work with signed numbers", why does the post use `unsigned int x;`?

Comment: Why the "(without considering overflow)" with `unsigned x;`?

Comment: @user9088013 what problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Of course unless the answer is [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)), all problems are XY problmes ;-)